# How do I apply SVD on complex matrices in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, complex-numbers, svd

I´m trying to implement on C++ opencv an algorithm which uses the SVD decomposition results (U, Sigma, V) from a complex matrix, however the SVD implementation on opencv doesn´t allow using complex matrices, Is there any method or transformation which I can use to apply the SVD of complex matrices on opencv?

Thanks in advance.